# How can I iterate on a Collection and use object's methods ? (differents Objects)

Tags: java

I have 2 different Objects(with their own methods) inside a Collection  :

```java
public class Hero {
[...]
  public int getLevel(){
    return level
  }
}
```

```java
public class Monster {
[...]
  public int getLevel(){
    return level
  }
}
```

I shuffle my Collection to randomly change the order of elements :

```java
List<Object> fighters = Arrays.asList(hero, monster);
Collections.shuffle(fighters);
```

After that, I need to iterate on the Collection and call Object's methods (they got the same name for both objects).

Is it possible ?
I tried with *for loop*, *Iterator* and I always receive error message :
`The method getLevel() is undefined for the type Object`

Example of my last tries:

## 1

```java
        Iterator<Object> iterator = fighters.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object ob = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("character level :" + ob.getLevel());
        }
```

## 2

```java
        for (Object p : fighters) {
            System.out.println("character level :" +  p.getLevel());
           ;
        }
```

Q: How can I iterate on a Collection and use Object methods?

Let me know if I can be more clear
(i didn't find  how to make a java snippet)

Comment: Why did you throw away type information on purpose? Do not collect them in a `List<Object>`. Use an interface to group their similarities and then have a list over that interface. Then you can also call the method.

Comment: Technically you can check the type with `instanceof` and then **cast**. Afterwards you can call the method again. But this usually, and especially in this case, indicates poor design. I.e. why throw away the type information in the first place.

Comment: Use an interface like `public interface HasLevel { int getLevel(); }`.

Comment: I put them in Collection because it's the only solution I thought of to randomly choose who will be first; Object was my only common property, that why I choose it as type. Thanks for your solutions!

Comment: Fair enough. Just introduce a common property that still has the method, thats why there are interfaces :)